# How to determine job dependency graph from Azure DevOps Timelines REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

My team has build YAML which has several jobs that `dependsOn` other jobs, but other jobs can run in parallel. I'm building a tool that will analyze our builds, and one of the things I want it to do is tell me build duration. This was trivial (last job finish time - first job start time) before "retry failed jobs" was introduced. Now however the simple "last job finished - first job start" calculation is not the value I care about when a job failed, was retried, and then was successful. I'm trying to calculate "wall clock time" a developer needs to wait before they can merge their PR, and flakiness is being tracked as a separate issue.

Using the REST API, I can use the [builds endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get all builds where `result == "succeeded" || result == "partiallySucceeded"`, and the [timeline endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) I can filter the timeline to get the list of records where `type == "job"`.

Without hardcoding my build's job dependency order (because it changes over time), how can I determine what the job dependencies are, so I can build a Gantt Chart of the build jobs, removing the time when the build wasn't running when the job was retried?

For example, say my build has 5 jobs: Init, Build Debug, Build Release, Test, Sign. The two Build jobs dependsOn Init, and Test dependsOn Build Debug, and Sign dependsOn Test and Build Release. I want some way to programmatically determine the job dependency graph.

Answer (score 1):

The build log doesn't contain job dependsOn information, I'm afraid you have to get YAML file via [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) REST API, and check job dependsOn in the file.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&versionDescriptor.version={branch}&api-version=6.1-preview.1`

If there are templates in the pipeline, you would need to get the templates by specifying their path via the same api.

Comment: Unfortunately that API returns 404 with a json body that includes the message `Build pipeline 1234 is not designer`. My build definition is spread across multiple yaml files using the template keyword, files commit in our repo.

Comment: The Yaml - Get api converts a definition to YAML. Since you have used YAML, you need to use Items - Get REST API. Regarding the templates, you need to get the templates by specifying their path via the same api. I have updated my reply, you could refer to it.

Comment: So I have to write my own yaml parser to recursively download yaml, assembly a "single" yaml the same way that Azure Pipelines does, and also know how to parse the "dependsOn" items myself :( Really feels like Azure DevOps is missing useful information in their REST APIs. Furthermore, my team uses "squash merge", and rebase dev branches, so I fear that a bunch of git hashes won't even exist when I run my tool and try to download the yaml.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't find anywhere has the  job dependsOn information, except in the YAML file. You may try to submit a feature request in the following link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion.

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Comment: It would have been the solution if I wasn't using yaml in my repo, but unfortunately I still don't have a solution to the problem I'm trying to solve. I created a suggestion more than a month ago, but there hasn't been any upvotes or any comments. I know it takes time to implement and deploy things that are accepted, but I fear my suggestion won't get worked on.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only get the dependsOn information from the YAML file currently. :-(