# Azure DevOps YAML pipelines BuildApi: is there a way to get the stage dependsOn value?

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops

Using the buildApi.getBuildTimeline() function I can get the build stages (TimelineRecord[]), the TimelineRecord.order doesn't seem to reflect the dependency (stage.dependsOn) graph, is there a way to resolve the stages' dependency graph?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `dependsOn` can only be found in YAML file for now.

There are the similar issues:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/timeline-rest-api-should-include-dependson/1361590

[How to determine job dependency graph from Azure DevOps Timelines REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978033/how-to-determine-job-dependency-graph-from-azure-devops-timelines-rest-api) (workaround here)

In addition, the [Yaml - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/yaml/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API **can't** get the YAML of muti-stages. So you could only get YAML file from repos.